# 'module' object is not callable in python roboticstoolbox by Peter Corke

Tags: python, plot, backend, robotics

Good morning everybody, I'm currently using the python Roboticstoolbox written by Peter Corke but I have a problem when trying to make the noodlelike plot of my robotic arm. The same error appears when trying to run the provided example:

[Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWRXA.png)

The error is the following:

```
 pyplot = rtb.backends.PyPlot()  # create a PyPlot backend
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

How can I make it work?

Comment: Where is that distribution `rtb` available? If running one of their examples produces an errors, I think it is best to open an issue with the project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is possible to find it here, at the github of Peter Corke:

https://petercorke.github.io/robotics-toolbox-python/arm_backend_pyplot.html

Comment: If you are certain that you tried the example with the latest version, then it's probably best to open an issue at the repository.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it! Thank you!